# PubSub message not getting pushed to dead-letter after max retry configured

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-pubsub, google-cloud-run

I have configured a dead letter for my Pub/Sub subscription (Subscription type PUSH) with a maximum delivery attempt of 5. Still, I am seeing more than 5 retries in the logs. The publisher and subscriber roles are assigned to topics.
Please check attached image for ref.
[image]
[image]

Compared it with other subscription and neccessary permissions.

Answer (score 0):

Can you confirm you have provided the [proper permissions](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/handling-failures#grant_forwarding_permissions)? The behavior you are seeing is often the result of one or both the permissions missing.

You can also look at the [available monitoring](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/handling-failures#monitor_forwarded_messages) to see the errors that the system is receiving when attempting to forward the message to the dead letter topic.